# Excel Evaluate based on formula

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I originally posted something similar to this in the SSRS forums but due to the limitation of SSRS it can't be done, well it appears not anyway so I am going to try it from a different angle.

I have 2 Excel documents called "Prop1" and "Prop2". In Prop2 there is a sheet called "Data", this is an exported SSRS report, in column DF are a number of functions all looking something like this `=(DD3*5)` running down the sheet, but not appearing on every line. Cell `DD3` contains a number exported from the report for example we will say 79.

I will drag Data from Prop2 and put the sheet in to Prop1, I want to then be able to run a Macro that Evaluates all the cells in the Data sheet that is now in Prop1 and anything that looks like the formula `=(DD3*` evaluates this as a proper Excel function so that when changing the value in DD3 it changes the calculation result.

Unfortunately this document is going to be given to a selection of people that know little of Excel so I need to automate this as much as possible.  I was trying to use the code :-

```
Sub test()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In ActiveWindow.RangeSelection
        cell.Value = Evaluate(cell.Formula)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

But not sure how to customize it to do what I have tried to explain.

Can anyone help as I am really running out of other options to make all this work.

Sorry I had some cell references to D33 and some to DD3 they should all be DD3 and I have changed the question accordingly.

Comment: Not sure what you mean mehow?

Comment: not sure what you are asking for, its unclear since no one has helped u yet

Comment: what kinda result that you expected from the code ?

Comment: Ok, more expanding, SSRS has no proper ability to export to Excel and maintain an excel functions i.e. if I populate a cell in SSRS with =(D33*Hours) when exported I get a column reading =(D33*5), =(D33*6) and so on depending on what the hour value is, once exported Excel thinks this is just text, if however I click in to the exported cell in Excel it then recognizes it as an excel formula, what I need help in writing is some code that evaluates all the cells that have =(D33* in then and shows them as an excel function rather than just plain text.  Hope that is a bit clearer, or perhaps not :(

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure but you can change `cell.Value = Evaluate(cell.Formula)`

with `cell.Formula = cell.Value`

I already tried it when put `'` in formula

Comment: Hi matzone, not sure if I have understood your suggestion correctly, are you asking is it possible to set the exported value to Evaluate(cell.Formula) if that is the case unfortunately not, once exported this value is just left as text and I am back to having to evaluate it a second time, assuming I am understanding you correctly!

Comment: @PJD .. It's tried like this .. A1=1 .. B1=2 .. C1='=A1+B1 .. then I select C1 .. continue execute the code .. so C1 will be 3 ..

Comment: Hi matzone thanks for trying to help, my output in excel look like you C1 output but only the formula is show as its just showing it as text, I need to get Excel to automatically realise that anything that shall we says has D33* in the cell is really an excel formula and needs to be treated as such.

Comment: @PJD .. sorry, what result you've got after you applied the changed code ?